# JAX-WS to return multiple values

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, glassfish, jax-ws

I am trying to code a simple webservice which will get to parameters and return three different parameters.

I can achieve this with following codes. But the problem is the setter method is also included in web service. For example I want to protect "setTransactionID" to be excluded in webservice methods. How do i modify the code ?

```
package OKS;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;

import javax.jws.WebParam;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService

public class CheckCredit {

@WebMethod

public Result GetResult(@WebParam(name="username") String username,@WebParam(name="password") String password) {

Result res= new Result();

    if ((username!=null)&&(password!=null)) {

        if ((username.equals("xyz"))&&(password.equals("123"))) {

            res.setResultType(1);

            res.setTransactionID("tr12128");

            res.setCredit(1220);

        } else {

            res.setResultType(0);

            res.setTransactionID("cr12128");

            res.setCredit(0);

        }

    } else {

        res.setResultType(0);

        res.setTransactionID("er12128");

        res.setCredit(0);

    }

    return res;

}
```

}

Result Class

```
package OKS;

public class Result {

int resultType;

String TransactionID;

int Credit;

public void setResultType(int resultType) {

    this.resultType = resultType;

}

public void setTransactionID(String transactionID) {

    TransactionID = transactionID;

}

public void setCredit(int credit) {

    Credit = credit;

}

public int getResultType() {

    return resultType;

}

public String getTransactionID() {

    return TransactionID;

}

public int getCredit() {

    return Credit;

}
```

}

This service compiles and works fine. But it also includes the setter method in WebService.
How can i exclude setter methods ?

Comment: Could you simply rename setTransactionID() to something like setTransactionID_please_dont_export_that_method(), or some neater name anyway?

Comment: Or could simply making setTransactionID() package private work?

Comment: Aaah, I think I figured you don't really care about the interface, but about security, right? In that case, you should probably be looking into stateful beans: http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.5/docs/statefulWebservice.html  It's not possible to secure little pieces of plain text XML data the way you are trying to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just dont want to get TransactionId in output.If it is, than just use @XmlTransient attribute on the get method.